# Avoid view on multiple tables querying all tables when not required

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

we are doing something like this

```
create view v1 
as 
select 'tab1' as table_name , * from table1
union All
select 'tab2' as table_name , * from table2
union All
select 'tab3' as table_name , * from table3
```

then in a SP,

```
declare @var = function_gettablename()
    select * from v1 where table_name = @var and datetoload = <ActualDate>

function_gettablename() = gives the table name based on parameters
```

datetoload = non clustered indexed column which is mutuallt exclusive on all the tables. ie one date would be available in one table only

Now the issue is that in execution plan :  using @var makes the view query all three tables rather than the one needed.

Is there a way it applies filter and then applied union all, rather than running union all and then applying filters.

Thanks
AB

Comment: Can you do this in your SP? `If @var = 'tab1' begin select * from table1 where datetoload = <ActualDate> end else if @var = 'tab2' begin select * from table2 where datetoload = <ActualDate> end else if @var = 'tab3' begin select * from table3 where datetoload = <ActualDate> end`

Comment: If the view's only purpose is to be called in the proc, I think you'd be better off with dynamic SQL or what @rs. suggests.  This view seems like it might be useful if you don't know which table has your date, but you have a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This -:

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Var = function_gettablename()
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ActualDate DATETIME
SET @ActualDate ='2013/2/14'

SET @sql = 'SELECT tab1 as '+@Var+' , * FROM table1 
            WHERE dateload ='+@ActualDate+ ' UNION ALL
            SELECT tab2 as '+@Var+' , * FROM table1 
            WHERE dateload ='+@ActualDate+' UNION ALL
            SELECT tab3 as '+@Var+',* FROM table1 
            WHERE dateload ='+@ActualDate

Exec(@Sql)
```

Comment: thanks for you comments, we are trying to not use IF statement and dynamic queries because the SP is very complex and these tables count can increase.

Comment: Just to add to above, looking for some way so that querying the view applies filter in the query and does not use the table not needed.

Comment: So the question is basically there are (n) number of complicated SPS trying to get data from (m) > 3 number of tables. the table name would come from a function name. What would be the best approach